# Unable to align chat messages according to the sender in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using RecyclerView. I'm passing the adapter a list of the Message objects. I want to organise or align the chat messages according to the sender. If the sender is the current user himself then the message will be aligned on the right, else on the left. Tried doing it in  a lot of ways. Still wasnt able to get the solution!

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private List<Message> Message;
    private Context context;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView message_text;
        public User user;
        public ViewGroup parent;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            message_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);

            user = Methods.getUserInstance(message_text.getContext());
        }
    }
    public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Message> message) {
        this.context = context;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public void add(int position, Message message) {
        Message.add(position, message);
    }

    @Override
    public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_message, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        vh.parent = parent;
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message m = Message.get(position);
        holder.message_text.setText(m.getText());
        if (holder.user.getUsername().equals(m.getUsername())) {
            //here goes the manipulation!
        }

        Toast.makeText(holder.message_text.getContext(), m.getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Message.size();
    }
}
```

And this is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="289dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/reciever_rounded_message"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="chakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakkachakka" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/reply_text"
    android:layout_width="289dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="some text here!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Align parent right if current user using Layoutparams.you can access any LayoutParams from code using View.getLayoutParams to align Parent if current user.

```
if (holder.user.getUsername().equals(m.getUsername())) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)message_text.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        message_text.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Comment: Hey! This is working! But It's not totally aligning it to the right. There is still some space left on the right side. Please help
!

Comment: @AshishKulkarni Then Remove padding in XML. i edited. if its works then please accept my answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You must take care of the `gravity` property of your view. This can be done programatically as:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message m = Message.get(position);
    holder.message_text.setText(m.getText());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.weight = 1.0f;        
    if (holder.user.getUsername().equals(m.getUsername())) {
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    } else {
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    }
    holder.message_text.setLayoutParams(params);        

    Toast.makeText(holder.message_text.getContext(), m.getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: No. Its not making any difference